# Logstash config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

question about logstash configuration
here is my logstash config:

```
  useragent {
    source => "cs_user_agent"
    target => "useragent"
    remove_field => ["cs_user_agent"]
  }

  mutate {
    rename => { "useragent" => "[hit][useragent]" }
  }
```

here is part of template:

```
        "useragent":{
          "type": "nested",
          "properties":{
            "build":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "device":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "major":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "minor":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "name":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "os":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "os_name":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            },
            "patch":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

and here is exception:

Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"stats", :_type=>"_doc", :_routing=>nil}, #LogStash::Event:0x3ac94d46], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"stats", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"X4RqWnQBFu_XrP68nSHP", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [hit.useragent] of type [text] in document with id 'X4RqWnQBFu_XrP68nSHP'. Preview of field's value: '{patch=4147, major=84, os=Other, minor=0, build=, name=Chrome, os_name=Other, device=Other}'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:266"}}}}}

What I ma missing? Is it logstash config error or es mapping error?

Comment: This error about logstash config. Can you share entire filter ?